# Paging arrays in mongodb subdocument

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a mongo collection with documents that have a schema structured like the following:

```
{ _id : bla,
  fname : foo,
  lname : bar,
  subdocs [ { subdocname : doc1
             field1 : one
             field2 : two
             potentially_huge_array : [...]
            }, ...
  ]
}
```

I'm using the ruby mongo driver that currently does not support elemMatch.  I use an aggregation when extracting from subdocs via a project, unwind and match pipeline.

What I would now like to do is to page results from the potentially_huge_array array contained in the subdocument.  I have not been able to figure out how to grab just a subset of the array without dragging the entire subdoc, huge array and all, out of the db into my app.

Is there some way to do this?

Would a different schema be a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how huge is huge, you definitely don't want it embedded into another document.

The main reason is that unless you always want the array returned with the document, you probably don't want to store it as part of the document.  How you can store it in another collection would depend on exactly how you want to access it.

Reviewing the types of queries you most often perform on your data will usually suggest the best schema - one that will allow you to be efficient about number of queries, the amount of data returned and ease of indexing the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you field really huge and changes often, just placed it in separate collection.